# How to avoid a vertical scrollbar in a table body to ruin the layout of the table by taking width

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

I'm in my first practice job as assistant to a developer and he has asked me to fix the layout of this table:

[image]

He was using 3 tables, one for the header, one for the body and another for the header and he said that putting it all in one table using header, footer and body would fix the cell alignment.

BUT, from what I've been reading the vertical scrollbar takes 16px from the width, so after changing it as requested the layout is still wrong.

The original code is using fixed width for every column and is actually inserted using javascript, php and ajax. As you can see CSS is hardly used, most of styling is inserted directly in the html.

```
            oHtml = "";             
            oHtml = oHtml + "<table class='tabInfoHistCliente' width='706px' height='200px'>";  
            oHtml = oHtml + "   <thead>";   
            oHtml = oHtml + "       <tr>";  
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <th class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' colspan='9' align='center'>ESTADISTICA RECEPCION LOTES</td>";  
            oHtml = oHtml + "       </tr>";  

            oHtml = oHtml + "       <tr>";    
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <th class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='80' >Fecha</td>";     
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <th class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='40' >Cant. Lotes</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <th class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='80' >Suma P.Humedo TM</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <th class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='70' >Suma P. Seco TM</td>";   
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <th class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='80' >Pond Ley Au oz/Tc</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <th class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='90' >Pond Ley Au gr/Tm</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <th class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='90' >Suma Total Fino Au lote gr</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <th class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='80' >Pond PIO US$/OZ</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <th class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='96' >Importe  US$</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "       </tr>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "   </thead>";  
            // TOTAL            
            oHtml = oHtml + "   <tbody class='tabInfoHistCliente' height='135px' style='overflow-y:scroll' >";    
            for (iFor = 0; iFor <= 7; iFor++) {   
                fTotales[iFor] = 0;
            }
            for (iFor = 0; iFor <= stringArray.length-1; iFor++) {   

                if (stringArray[iFor].length > 0) {  
                    iTotReg++;  

                    sPosXY = stringArray[iFor].split("()");
                                        //alert(stringArray[iFor]);
                    fTotales[0] = fTotales[0] + parseFloat(sPosXY[1]);
                    fTotales[1] = fTotales[1] + parseFloat(sPosXY[2]);
                    fTotales[2] = fTotales[2] + parseFloat(sPosXY[3]);
                    fTotales[3] = fTotales[3] + parseFloat(sPosXY[4]);
                    fTotales[4] = fTotales[4] + parseFloat(sPosXY[5]);
                    fTotales[5] = fTotales[5] + parseFloat(sPosXY[6]);
                    fTotales[6] = fTotales[6] + parseFloat(sPosXY[7]);
                    fTotales[7] = fTotales[7] + parseFloat(sPosXY[8]);


                    oHtml = oHtml + "       <tr>";
                    oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdDat' width='80'>" + sPosXY[0] + "</td>";
                    oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdDat' width='40' align='right' >" + xFormatNumber(sPosXY[1],0) + "</td>";
                    oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdDat' width='80' align='right' >" + xFormatNumber(sPosXY[2],2) + "</td>";
                    oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdDat' width='70' align='right' >" + xFormatNumber(sPosXY[3],2) + "</td>";
                    oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdDat' width='80' align='right' >" + xFormatNumber(sPosXY[4],2) + "</td>";
                    oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdDat' width='90' align='right' >" + xFormatNumber(sPosXY[5],2) + "</td>";
                    oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdDat' width='90' align='right' >" + xFormatNumber(sPosXY[6],2) + "</td>";
                    oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdDat' width='80' align='right' >" + xFormatNumber(sPosXY[7],2) + "</td>";
                    oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdDat' width='80' align='right' >" + xFormatNumber(sPosXY[8],2) + "</td>";
                    oHtml = oHtml + "       </tr>"; 

                    arrResCompras[0] = fTotales[0];
                    arrResCompras[1] = fTotales[1];
                    arrResCompras[2] = fTotales[2];
                    arrResCompras[3] = fTotales[3];
                    arrResCompras[4] = fTotales[4];
                    arrResCompras[5] = fTotales[5];
                    arrResCompras[6] = fTotales[6];
                    arrResCompras[7] = fTotales[7];
                }
            }           
            oHtml = oHtml + "   </tbody>";  

            // TOTAL            
            oHtml = oHtml + "   <tfoot class='tabInfoHistCliente' height='15px' >";   
            oHtml = oHtml + "       <tr>";    
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='80' >TOTALES</td>";   
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='40' >" + xFormatNumber(fTotales[0],0) + "</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='80' >" + xFormatNumber(fTotales[1],2) + "</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='70' >" + xFormatNumber(fTotales[2],2) + "</td>";      
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='80' >" + xFormatNumber(fTotales[3],2) + "</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='90' >" + xFormatNumber(fTotales[4],2) + "</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='90' >" + xFormatNumber(fTotales[5],2) + "</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='80' >" + xFormatNumber(fTotales[6],2) + "</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "           <td class='tabInfoHistCliente_tdTit' width='96' >" + xFormatNumber(fTotales[7],2) + "</td>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "       </tr>"; 
            oHtml = oHtml + "   </tfoot>";
            oHtml = oHtml + "</table>";
```

So my question is: Is any way to fix the layout? Adding 16px to the last header column doesn't seem to work (80px in body, 96px in header and footer) . 
I've seen solutions using jquery but I'm not sure if jquery is being used at all. The html is a mess of libraries insertions that are not being used.
I'think I've seen scrollbars that doesn't take space and appear only when you hover the mouse on them.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you OK with the table getting taller than 135px?

Comment: Sure, I'm allowed to fix small changes

Comment: I'm putting the answer here since I think I can find a dupe for this but if you just need to get rid of the scrollbar, remove `height='135px' style='overflow-y:scroll'`.

Comment: The body rows are pulled from a database so removing the scroll isn't an option since it can get as big as 500 rows. I thought there was an easy option like a floating scrollbar that doesn't take space

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height from the table and tablebody tags. That way the table will expand to fix however many rows are Fred to it from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a style `word-break: break-all` to your **td** element.
It will do all the magic.